# Disabled Azure Function Billing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-billing

**TLDR;**

Assuming my azure function (consumption plan) is disabled, would I still have to pay for request attempts sent to it (NotFound response)?

**In Depth:**

I have azure function created (consumption plan) with multiple HTTP triggers configured (myazfunc.azurewebsites.com/api/add, api/check, etc..)

As you know, Azure allows to change the state of every one of this triggers (Disabled/Enabled).

If I disabled one of them and then try to call it, I get a NotFound response (which is fine).

So, my question is, would I be billed for requests sent to this trigger even though it's disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Azure functions only pay for computing resources for the functions that are active. Its usage plan is based on resource consumption and executions per second.
- The Consumption plan dynamically adds and removes instances of the Functions host based on the number of incoming events.

For more info on Azure functions you can refer [HERE](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/functions/#overview)

**REFERENCES:**
[Azure Functions pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/functions/)

Comment: Just to clarify, the function has multiple HTTP triggers, and I disable only one of the triggers. Invoking the disabled HTTP trigger will not be counted for billing right? (The whole function is not disabled)

Comment: afaik yes, it will be billed only for functions that are running.